# How to check if a string only contains numbers in Swift 2?

Tags: string, swift2, xcode7

Before Swift 2 I used this extension to check if a string only is made out of numbers:

```
func isNumbersOnly() -> Bool {
        let regexNumbersOnly = NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^0-9].*", options: nil, error: nil)!
        return regexNumbersOnly.firstMatchInString(self, options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, self.length())) != nil
}
```

but now with Swift 2 I get the error

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSRegularExpression' with an
>   argument list of type '(pattern: String, options:
>   NilLiteralConvertible, error: NilLiteralConvertible)'

Is there a better known way now? Thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 2 NSRegularExpression "throws" so you have to use it with `try`.

Also you can't pass `nil` for options anymore: if you don't want to specify options, pass an empty array (same for `firstMatchInString`).

And `self.length()` should become `self.characters.count`.

Last note: if the goal is to determine if a String contains only numbers, and since you're naming it "isNumbersOnly", the resulting Boolean should be true if there's only numbers: it's currently the inverse. I've fixed this in my example.

Ignoring errors:

```
let regexNumbersOnly = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^0-9].*", options: [])
return regexNumbersOnly.firstMatchInString(self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) == nil
```

With proper error handling:

```
do {
    let regexNumbersOnly = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".*[^0-9].*", options: [])
    return regexNumbersOnly.firstMatchInString(self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count)) == nil
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.description)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using regular expressions, you can use `CharacterSet`s to check for the existence (or absence) of certain characters. To check if the string is only digits you can use the following:

```
extension String {
    var isDigits: Bool {
        if isEmpty { return false }
        // The inverted set of .decimalDigits is every character minus digits
        let nonDigits = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
        return rangeOfCharacter(from: nonDigits) == nil
    }
}
```

This method can be applied to any type of `CharacterSet` and, in my opinion, is a lot cleaner than using regex strings.

Comment: This will return true for an empty String

Comment: @Leon thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the example code.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2 has adjusted the error-handling process; you should now `try` the call, not specifying an `error` and be prepared to catch an exception.

E.g.

```
do {
    let regexNumbersOnly = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ..., options: nil)
    ... etc ...
} catch _ {}
```

... given that you're electing not to handle error states.

Comment: one case where `try!` is probably preferable.

Comment: Okay, well I'm relatively new to the syntax myself, I mainly wanted to convey the policy reason for the change in `init` and your need to try/catch. I'll mark as community wiki to get the code improved.

Comment: Basically, if you don't want to catch the error (you are using `_`), you don't need `do { try ...} catch {}`, you can write just `let regex = try! ...`. I think this is preferable in this case because you don't depend on any external variables and the regular expression init should always succeed.